# Iterate through an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

My code looks like this:

```
void main()
{
    int vect[10], i;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        vect[i] = i*2;

    printf("Vector: ");

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d ", vect[i]);

    printf("\n");
```

When executing it, it will always show me this kind of output:
[image]

To make it just show the elements I entered (the first five; 0 2 4 6 8) I must use a counter or is there a way of telling it to only show me those elements?

Is there a reason why the elements 5, 6, 7 and 9 are always the same but the 8th changes every time? I rewrote the program to change how it shows the elements and it is the same way: it shows the five elements I entered, then three that remain always constant, then one that changes every time the program is executed and then a last constant one. Why is this?

Comment: You *do* know that `int vect[10]` is uninitialised? You set the first 5 elements, and the next 5 elements still have indeterminate values. You cannot draw any conclusions or explanations for those other 5 elements.

Comment: You can use `int vect[10] = { 0 }` to initialize the vector to all zeroes.

Comment: So I can't set a vector of X elements wihout initializing them all? If I want to create a vector and them keep adding elements to it, iterating only through those I intialized, should I use a list instead? @WeatherVane

Comment: @Xayide you can, but the problem is you are referencing those elements which you have *not* initialised,. and then asking why *undefined behaviour* is exhibiting what it does..

Comment: It's not good practice, I suppose is it? @WeatherVane I come from learning Python and lists there are way easier to understand

Comment: @Xayide this is not a list, it's an array. C does not have lists instrinsically, you have to make them yourself.

Comment: @ddriver *"They would be indeterminate only if the array is not used at all."* Is this something like Schrödinger's cat?

Comment: @WeatherVane - there are two sides to it - an uninitialized value may not even have any storage allocated when you attempt to read it, however in the case of an array - it is declared with a static size, and some of it is initialized. So while the last 5 array elements are not initialized, the array is at least partially initialized. I am unclear on what happens in this exact situation, but if I had to guess, I'd say the values are determinate, just arbitrary, as memory is not cleared on deallocation it will simply happen to have some older values. So nothing like the cat.

Comment: @ddriver indeterminate - arbitrary ~ semantics! They are undefined and so is any behaviour involving them.

Comment: @WeatherVane - an indeterminate value might come from "anywhere", a garbage value comes from its proper storage location reserved in the binary layout. I am unclear on how the standard handles partially initialized arrays. It says "an object" but an array is just about as much of an object as an array element. At least when it comes to brace initializers, it seems that initializing at least one of the total number of elements qualifies the entire object as initialized. But this is not a case of brace initialization.

Answer (score 7):

`int vect[10]` indices 5-9 are not initialised- you need to assign something to them otherwise they will (probably) return garbage, as this is undefined behaviour ([C99 standard, section 5.1.2 "Execution environments"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)). You can also define `vect` as static, i.e. `static int vect[10]`, since static variables will be automatically initialised to 0, and a static int array will have all elements automatically initialised to 0.

Comment: Cheers, this excellent response helped me solve a very difficult problem that I was having.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `vect` is an automatic local array which is not initialized explicitly upon definition. So, at that point, all the element values are indeterminate.

To quote `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.[...]

In the first for loop, you only initialize 5 elements, the rest elements are uninitialized and they contains indeterminate values.

Trying to read indeterminate values invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related, Annex J, same standard, for undefined behaviour

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate.

Once your program exhibits UB, nothing is guaranteed.

FWIW, `void main()` should at least be `int main(void)`.